# Is there a word for the relationship between my cousin's family and mine?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, kinship-terms

My mother's brother is my "uncle". His son is my "cousin". His wife is my "aunt". Each of these words names a specific person based on their familial relationship to me. Together the three of them make up a family of their own. Is there a way to name that family as it relates to me? This would be similar to how "in-laws" refers to a married couple as they relate to me via my marriage, if I were married (He's single, ladies).

Comment: Why not just call them “*your uncle’s family*”?  Choose *uncle* over *aunt* since your uncle is more closely related.

Comment: Or your cousin's family, for that matter.

Answer (score 4):

**parents** - father & mother
**grandparents** - grandfather & grandmother
**siblings** - brother & sister
**[niblings](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/4773/nibling)** - nephew & niece
**[piblings](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pibling)** - uncle & aunt

The latter is pending approval as of now: [There isn't a word for it!](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1570791/)

Comment: If they get approved, I vote "pibnib" for the family comprising niblings and piblings, as it relates to one.

Comment: As long as we are being whimsical, can we use "outlaws" for the relatives of a divorced spouse?